# VB.Net WebClient.DownloadFile() EXTREMELY SLOW

Tags: vb.net, performance, webclient

I am in need to create a database using history quotes from Yahoo API which returns a .csv file, so I developed a VB.NET project using webclient.downloadfile to fetch the csv and then fill the data into my own SQL database.

My codes worked, but I had a problem that the process of downloading the file itself takes well over 10 to 30 seconds during each loop. After reading a lot of threads I have already added

```
(WebClient).Proxy = Nothing
```

on form load, but this didn't help at all.

If I were to download these files in my browser (IE/Chrome), it will take less than a second before the save dialog shows up.

Here's what I used to achieve this task, unimportant codes have been omitted:

```
Dim GetIDCMD As String = "select StockID from dbo.[BaseData] where MarketType = 'SHA'"
Dim GetIDAdpt As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(GetIDCMD, conn)
Dim DT As New DataSet
GetIDAdpt.Fill(DT, "Set")

For i = 0 To DT.Tables("Set").Rows.Count - 1 Step 1
    StockID = StrDup(6 - Len(DT.Tables("Set").Rows(i).Item(0).ToString), "0") & Trim(DT.Tables("Set").Rows(i).Item(0).ToString)
    Dim urlcsv = "http://ichart.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=" & StockID & ".ss&a=00&b=01&c=2004&d=" & Now.Month - 1 & "&e=" & Now.Day & "&f=" & Now.Year & "&g=d"
    '  sample URL     http://ichart.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=600030.ss&a=00&b=01&c=2004&d=11&e=15&f=2014&g=d&ignore=.csv   
    Try
        WEB.DownloadFile(urlcsv, "TEMP.csv")
        success = True

        '''

    Catch ex As Exception
        templog = Mid(ex.ToString(), 1, InStr(ex.ToString, vbCrLf)) & vbCrLf
        success = False

        '''

    End Try
    If success = True Then


        '''


    End If
Next
```

Does this has anything to do my internet connection settings?

Will it be faster if I use HttpWebRequest?

Comment: What's the file size? The fact that a dialog shows up does not mean anything. It still needs to download the file, while you wait.

Comment: Typically these CSVs are around 30~50KBs, the data streaming should take almost no time at all

Comment: While I test downloading one file at a time with the downloadfile code, I recorded timelapse ranging from 500ms to a whopping 36000ms, and sometimes it just threw an exception that the yahoo server accidentally closed the connection.

Comment: Google "yahoo ichart throttling" to learn more.

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you for the help, this explained why sometimes I got connections closed because during testing the codes I can send multiple of thousands of requests per hour. But downloading from browsers never seemed to be affected, if they really throttle my request on an IP basis , wouldn't that be also impacting browser requests?

Comment: Hans' explanation sounds reasonable. To do a clean test, wait an hour, try 1 download from browser, wait 5 min, then try 1 from code. Don't throw 10000 per hour for now. You can then try to increase time between downloads, see when performance starts to drop. I'd expect 1 request every 5 seconds should not cause any throttling.